# Find $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$ by looking at a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Given the Fourier series:

$$F(x)=\sin{x}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^n} \cos{nx}$$

How do I find $a_0, a_1, a_2$ when $$a_0=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) dx$$ and $$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \cos{n x} dx$$

? Also, what is f(x) in this case?

I'm aware that this is a basic question, but I simply can't make sense of this for some reason.

Comment: Your expression is already in the form of a Fourier series, so you just need to read off the coefficients from what you have.  There is no constant term, so $a_0=0$, and for example $a_1=\frac{1}{5 \pi}$, etc.

Comment: So $\frac {1}{5^n}$ is my $f(x)$ in this case? My professor's answers are $a_0=0, a_1=\frac {1}{5}$ and $a_2=\frac {1}{5^2}$

Comment: Note that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx) \cos(mx) = 0$ for $n \ne m \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Now you should be able to evaluate the integrals using this orthogonality. I think $f(x)$ is intended to be $F(x)$ if those are your professor's answers.